# How to organize indexing process in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, search, indexing, gae-search

I have some text files with data to be indexed in my search-app on google app engine. I just don't understand when should I execute a function that puts all docs into index.

Currently I am trying to perform it in get-request on some admin page. But if I use all data then indexing process takes too much time to be run in get-request.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store the data in the datastore (if it's more than 10K) then fire off a task to perform the indexing, and return a response to the user.

You haven't said if your using python, java or go.

If your using python look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred for info about the deferred lib, which is an easy way to start using tasks with python, alternately start reading up on tasks.